How to get red/green solid candlestick in eCharts graph
I'm trying to get red/green candlesticks in a eCharts graph starting by the example on eCharts site.
The starting example it's called "Large Scale Candlestick" that generates random data from a custom function called generateOHLC.
ORIGINAL EXAMPLE LINK
In an other example there's a link that gets data from a JSON file also from eCharts site you can see at this link: https://echarts.apache.org/...
The values ​of each array (in the big array) ​are respectively [date ,open, close, low, high, volume]
Now, I have taken some of this value and I have adapted it to get an other value in the inners array with this small easy JavaScript code:
data.forEach(function (point, point_index){
  point.push (   getSign(data, point_index, point[1], point[2], 2)   )
  //console.log(point)
})

by using the same function getSign used from the previous example.
So the last value added (pushed in the array as 1 or -1) should make the candle turn red or green.
You can see the result of the adapted example here:
ADAPTED ECHART EXAMPLE
So, why the candles are always red and the ones in the first example are red and green?
Where's my error and what I'm doing wrong?

Your error is in the assumption that the sign value in the data array is responsible for the coloring. This is not the case. In fact, the sign value is not even used for the candlestick series in this example you linked (only for the visualMap to color the bars). If you remove the sign completely from the data, the chart doesnt change, see here.
Take a look at the candlestick data property. The red / green coloring depends on wether open is smaller or larger than close. As a first step it should be easier to go from this offical example as it has less complexity. From there you can transfer your data into a dataset and use encode to specify the dimensions in the same way as they are expected by the candlestick data property.
To summarize: Your candles are always red because the dataset dimension that encodes for the open part of the candle body is always smaller than the dimension that encodes for the close part of the candle body.

Code of the minimal candlestick example in case the link dies some day:
option = {
  xAxis: {
    data: ['2017-10-24', '2017-10-25', '2017-10-26', '2017-10-27']
  },
  yAxis: {},
  series: [
    {
      type: 'candlestick',
      data: [
        [20, 34, 10, 38],    // red because 'open' (first dimension) is smaller than 'close' (second dimension)
        [40, 35, 30, 50],    // green because 'close' (second dimension) is smaller than 'open' (first dimension)
        [31, 38, 33, 44],
        [38, 15, 5, 42]
      ]
    }
  ]
};


Hi @Matthias Mertens. So what's the use of getSign function code in the first example provided directly form echarts? It checks the opening/closing value for each candle and adds -1,1 at the end. Why if the color of the candles red/green it's checked directly from echarts? Also the example you are usign to explain that uses series.data (that I don't want to use), instead the one provided in the question uses to insert data dataset: { source: data, }. So can you explain me this? P.S. Beautiful Dog and let's hope the links don't die, otherwise you know how many funerals there will be

This is taken directly as example from echarts: https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=candlestick-large and adds a -1,1 at the end. Starting from easy things it's too much easy. Let's add some complexity to the code to understand please.

P.P.S. Not true that all values are close < open. I updated the mod sample. look @ line 36: the close it's more than open. Also volumns are red and green, but candlesticks no.

P.P.P.S. Also the buttons "reset zoom" does nothing when pressed. But this is an other problem.

The sign is only used to color the bars via a visualMap.
You seem to not understand what encode does. After realizing that it occurs to me that you have your dimensions swapped up.  Setting encode.y = [1,2,3,4] should fix your issue.

OK! Was encode the problem. Problem has been fixed. But I actually didn't understand the encode very well. What I'm saying is that I would like to know for example if in the tooltip the params are passed sorted with the encode or not. Also, if I give the same data to the graph as line rather than candlestick, what it's the value that takes the line? The first after date (so array[1]) or the encode value provided? Also I didn't know -1,1 was used to color the bars via visualMap. Where is this written in the documentation? Could you please link it? Anyway Tnx. U solved that problem

Also I got sometimes in my graph on local on my computer (it's not the same as example and I can't link it) some color values that don't match from bar and candlestick also after encode [1,2,3,4]. This happens very now and again, but happens. And an other thing: if i don't want to give red/green color to volume bars and I want it all the same color (eg. azure), how to do it?

Pls read the documentation: encode, visualMap, itemStyle

too much to read. I'm not so good in english so i'm trying to translating with google. Anyway you didn't answer to comments: bars all of same colors, encode it's after or before tooltip? Also I don't have understand the "Visual encoding" part in encode documentation.
